# How do I continue with this differential equation from the Brachistochrone problem with friction to get the correct parametric solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, parametrization

I'm stuck in getting the parametric solution to the Brachistochrone problem WITH friction. I've followed up to [step 30](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html), but I don't understand how the results in 32 and 33 were calculated.

In the image below is my work so far. I feel like I'm missing something; if anyone could help out, I would massively appreciate it.
Trying the substitution of $y' = \cot(\frac{\theta}{2})$ by inspection of possible trigonometric identities present in the differential equation:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{A}{y - \mu x} &= \frac{1 + \cot(\frac{\theta}{2})^2}{(1 + \mu \cot(\frac{\theta}{2}))^2}\\
    y - \mu x &= A\frac{(1 + \mu \cot(\frac{\theta}{2}))^2}{1 + \cot(\frac{\theta}{2})^2}\\
    y - \mu x &= A\left(\frac{1 + \mu \cot(\frac{\theta}{2})}{\csc(\frac{\theta}{2})}\right)^2\\
    y - \mu x &= A\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2} + \mu \frac{\frac{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}}{\frac{1}{sin\frac{\theta}{2}}}\right)^2\\
    y - \mu x &= A\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2} + \mu \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2\\
    y - \mu x &= A\left(\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} + 2\mu\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} + \mu^2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\
    y - \mu x &= A\left((1 - \cos\theta) + \mu \sin\theta + \mu^2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

This is as far as I've gotten. On the Wolfram alpha site, the steps are not clearly shown and hence I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
[Wolfram Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzn4s.png)